# How to explode BOM(Bill of Material) in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I Have in Microsoft Excel(2010)

[image: This is What I have in excel]

What I want to see when I Click the (-) sign

[image: Level 1 and Level 2]

So to Conclude the (+) sign is to show all the Level 0.1-0.3 While the (-) sign could choose to either Show Level 0.1 and 0.2 or just purely Level 0.1

I hope to do this through VBA but if there is alternative I wouldn't mind trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the "groups" function in Excel. If you haven't many rows and aren't interested in automation, you select the rows you want to hide/group (in your example, rows (3-5) and hit group.